# OSX Maven issues after homebrew maven opgrade

Tags: java, macos, maven, version

Immediately after I upgraded my Mac from maven 3.6.0 to 3.6.3 with homebrew, I was no longer able to build my maven project.  I've been through torrents of version dependency problems, etc, but I'm hoping to avoid stepping through any more of that stuff than I need to.  And before I continue, I wanted to bounce this off of you guys to see if it indicates anything ominous, or if it's ops normal (since I've never paid too much attention to it in the past.)  In question is the variance in java version numbers between mvn --version and java -version, i.e., 1.8.0_191 vs 14.0.1:

> $ java -version java version "1.8.0_191" Java(TM) SE Runtime
> Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
> (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
>
> mvn --version Apache Maven 3.6.3
> (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f) Maven home:
> /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec Java version: 14.0.1, vendor:
> N/A, runtime:
> /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/14.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "mac os x",
> version: "10.15.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first one is based on the default location on Mac and default selected Java and the second one comes via JAVA_HOME env variable I suppose... I never use homebrew to upgrade my Maven version.... and JDK is done via SDKMAN....

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my JAVA_HOME variable somehow evaporated in the homebrew upgrade.  Once I set that, all 12 million problems disappeared instantly.  Thanks for the comment khmarbaise!